# how do i change duplicate entry (unique value date) error into other message such as the date already booked

Tags: php, mysql

i create an website which is i had create date validation, change the date value in database as 'unique value' but it will view duplicate entry '12-1-2015' for example, how do i change it into a message  or popup tell 'Sorry the date had been reserve. .

this is my code of validation but not working. .

```
<?php


include 'connection.php';

$date = $_POST['date'];
$rand = rand ();
session_start();
$_SESSION['random']=$rand;
$type = $_POST['typeofballroom'];
$setup = $_POST['setup'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$conNum = $_POST['contactnumber'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$themes = $_POST['theme'];
$menu = $_POST['menu'];
$note = $_POST['notes'];



$query = "SELECT * FROM ballroom_form WHERE date = '$date' ";
$result = mysql_query($query);




$person = mysql_fetch_array($result);



if($date == $person['date']) {
echo "unvalid refference number";

}


else
{
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO ballroom_form  (`ID`,`random_number`,`ballroom_type`,`set_up`,`date`,`name`,`contact_number`,`email`,`themes`,`menu`,`note`) VALUES (NULL,'$rand','$type','$setup','$date','$name','$conNum','$email','$themes','$menu','$note')") or die(mysql_error());
echo "user has been added";
header ('location: randomNum.php'); 
}



?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: its seems like it does't read the 'if' statement when i fill the same date it directly procced into 'else'statement you can test my form website at phytohotel.webege.com - @Reti43

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easy way

```
if($date == $person['date']) {

 header("location:your_page.php?Status=no");
}
```

in your "your_page.php" add this or use popup script inside php {}

```
<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['Status']=='no')){?>

                <h3 >invalid reference number</h3>  
                    <?php }
```